# Scope which accesses multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following configuration and I'm trying to write a scope to give me all the orders where either the order.buying_store.name equals a search term, or the order.buying_store.company.name equals that same search term.  The scope as I've written is yielding an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "company"
```

My Setup:

```
class Company
  has_many :stores
end 

class Store
  belongs_to :company
end

class Order
  belongs_to :buying_store, class_name: 'Store', foreign_key: 'buying_store_id', required: true 
  belongs_to :selling_store, class_name: 'Store', foreign_key: 'selling_store_id', required: true

  scope :with_buying_counterpart_like, ->(search_term) { joins(:buying_store).where(['buying_store.name = ? OR buying_store.company.name = ?', search_term, search_term]) }

end
```

I also tried:

```
  scope :with_buying_counterpart_like, ->(search_term) { joins(:buying_store, :company).where(['buying_store.name = ? OR company.name = ?', search_term, search_term]) }
```

but it yields the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Order' to association named 'company'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try joining on :company also but it's like it can't see that table.

ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Order' to association named 'company'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Order' to association
>   named 'company'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Your second approach is the right one but flawed. You need to have it like below

```
scope :with_buying_counterpart_like, ->(search_term) { joins(buying_store: [:company]).where(['buying_store.name = ? OR company.name = ?', search_term, search_term]) }
```

That is, you need to have `company` **nested** with `buying_store`, as you don't have a association between `Order` and `Comapny`

**Update:**

Also when writing *string notation* of `where`, you need to write the exact **table names** instead of **association names**, so the final query would be

```
scope :with_buying_counterpart_like, ->(search_term) { joins(buying_store: [:company]).where(['stores.name = ? OR companies.name = ?', search_term, search_term]) }
```

Comment: Thanks! The join is happy now, but the where clause still yields the following error:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "buying_store"

Comment: @TamlynR Try this query `scope :with_buying_counterpart_like, ->(search_term) { joins(buying_store: [:company]).where(['stores.name = ? OR companies.name = ?', search_term, search_term]) }`

Answer (score 1):

You use **company** in scope, but you not joins table company
Try something like that

```
class Order
  with_options class_name: 'Store', required: true  do
    belongs_to :buying_store, foreign_key: 'buying_store_id'
    belongs_to :selling_store, foreign_key: 'selling_store_id'
  end

  scope :with_buying_counterpart_like, (lambda do |search_term| 
    joins(buying_store: :company)
      .where('stores.name = :term OR companies.name = :term', term: search_term)
  end)    
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that and it gives me errror: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "buying_store"

Comment: change table name  buying_store to store, because table buying_store is missing

Comment: That doesn't work either - ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Order' to association named 'store'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: what are names of your tables? store or stores? company or companies?

Comment: As per Rails convention - i.e. the tables are stores and companies while the models are in the singular. 
But joining to singular or plural - neither seems to work.

Comment: so, why do you use company.name in your condition instead of companies.name?